# Expected unqualified-id before token error

Tags: c++

I'm starting with C++ and I can't figure this out. I have three classes and am trying to implement a queue. (Doesn't matter if it works or not now, i just need to fix this error)

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include "queue.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    queue fronta();

    queue.add(10); // <- expected unqualified-id before ‘.’ token
}
```

queue.h:

```
#ifndef QUEUE_H
#define QUEUE_H

#include "queueItem.h"

class queue {
private:
    queueItem* first;
    queueItem* last;

public:
    queue();
    void add(int number);
    int get(void);
    bool isEmpty();
};

#endif  /* QUEUE_H */
```

queueItem.h:

```
#ifndef QUEUEITEM_H
#define QUEUEITEM_H

class queueItem{
private:
    int value;
    queueItem* next;

public:
    queueItem(int value);

    int getValue();
    queueItem* getNext();
    void setNext(queueItem* next);
};

#endif  /* QUEUEITEM_H */
```

From what I've googled, it's usually related to extraneous semicolon, bracket or such. I found nothing of sorts though

Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call `.add()` on the class type `queue`, you need to call it on the object you have created! In your case, that would be `fronta.add(10);`.

Also, your syntax for creating `fronta` is wrong. Use `queue fronta;`.

Comment: This is **not** the most vexing parse. It is simply and unambiguously a function declaration, just like `int f();`. The most vexing parse involves construction of a temporary as a function argument; see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse.

Answer (score 2):

The line `queue fronta();` is declaring a function which returns an object of type `queue` and takes no argument. This is likely not what you want. Use `queue fronta;` instead.

Secondly, you have to call the function `add()` on an *instance* of `queue`, not on the class itself (that would be the case if the function were `static`, but in that case you would use `::` instead of `.`). Therefore:

```
queue.add(10); // ERROR!
fronta.add(10); // OK
```